# Intercept response code in webview using google doc to display pdf

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview that loads a google doc with a flyer (pdf, from the web) in it.  Some of the flyers are live on my website but others aren't, but I have them coded in the app so when they become available the user will see them.
The google doc in the webview works great with flyers that are available but ones that aren't available yet I get a error-type message in the google doc.  I would like to intercept the 404 response code error from the URL that has the flyer (pdf).  How do I do this?

Current code:

```
/*opens in app using google docs*/
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);      
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+round_num_url);
//round_num_url is the url for my flyer
```

Message in google doc in webview for flyers unavailable - "Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists. You can also try to download the original document by clicker here"

EDIT: doesn't work yet (crashes) after taking suggestions from @x-code

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(round_num_url);
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            huc.connect();
            if (huc.getResponseCode() != 404) {
              // the pdf is available, continue with your code that loads the web view
              // ...
            } else {
              // the pdf is not available, you may need to notify the user
              // ...
            }
            huc.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Google docs will receive a 404 when it tries to access your broken URL, it is not going to return a 404 to the web view, because the Google docs URL is valid.

You should first test your own URL (the URL of your PDF) by trying to load it with for example the AndroidHttpClient and an HttpHead request. If this returns a 404 don't bother trying to load gdocs.

Here is some example code. I used HttpUrlConnection because that is the method recommended by Android docs for new code:

```
HttpUrlConnection huc = new HttpUrlConnection(round_num_url);
huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
huc.connect();
if (huc.getResponseCode() != 404) {
  // the pdf is available, continue with your code that loads the web view
  // ...
} else {
  // the pdf is not available, you may need to notify the user
  // ...
}
huc.disconnect();
```

I have not compiled this code, and you may have to wrap it in a try / catch block before it will compile.

Update: I had to modify the code to make it work, as suggested above:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        if (huc.getResponseCode() != 404) {
            // url is available
        } else {
            // url is not available
        }
    } finally {
        huc.disconnect();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    ;
} catch (IOException e) {
    ;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of using those methods? I'm a newbie.

Comment: @tsell75: I made some some changes in order to compile and test my example. This version worked fine for me.

Comment: something is going wrong for me at the if statement line.